# Host key does not match cached key in WinSCP through batch file script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, winscp

When I trying to connect  a server from other server through some batch script using WinSCP.

But when I see the error log I found below message.

> The server's host key does not match the one WinSCP has in cache. This
>   means that either the server administrator has changed the host key,
>   the server presents different key under certain circumstance, or you
>   have actually connected to another computer pretending to be the
>   server.

Could you check why I am getting this error provide resolution step by step for the same.

Thanks,
Venkatesh

Comment: I believe this questions is related to network configuration (WinSCP) rather than 
 programming. You may have a chance to get answer at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) or better ask on [WinSCP Support Forum](https://winscp.net/forum/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [WinSCP documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_security_breach):

> **Warning - Potential security breach!**
>
> This message, followed by *“The
> server’s host key does not match the one WinSCP has in cache”*, means
> that WinSCP has connected to the SSH server before, knows what its
> host key should be, but has found a different one.
>
> This may mean that a malicious attacker has replaced your server with
> a different one, or has redirected your network connection to their
> own machine. On the other hand, it may simply mean that the
> administrator of your server has accidentally changed the key while
> upgrading the SSH software; this shouldn’t happen but it is
> unfortunately possible. Another legitimate reason for the host key
> change is that the address, you are connecting to, load balances to a
> set of SSH servers. ...
>
> You should contact your server’s administrator and see whether they
> expect the host key to have changed. If so, verify the new host key in
> the same way as you would if it was new.
>
> Read more about [verifying host keys](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key).

---

See also [Verifying the host key or certificate in script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey).